# Как сделать это асинхронным?

Tags: javascript, node.js, асинхронность

Приложение NodeJS. Есть вот такой кусочек кода:

```
var isAccepted;
offers.getOffer({tradeOfferId: offer.tradeofferid}, function (err, o) { 
   if (err || (o == null) || (typeof o.response.offer.trade_offer_state == "undefined")) {
      helper.msg('Cant load offer state. It can be accepted, but we cant check it. Returning');
      isAccepted = false;
      return;
   }
   if (o.response.offer.trade_offer_state == "3") {
   isAccepted = true;
   }
   else {
   isAccepted = false;
   }
   return;
});

if (!isAccepted) {
   io.emit('tradeoffer-msg', { steamid: offer.steamid_other, type: 6 });
   return;
}
```

Проблема в том, что `if (!isAccepted)` выполняется раньше, чем мы получаем результат от сервера в `offers.getOffer`.
Я, конечно, мог бы поместить

```
 if (!isAccepted) {
   io.emit('tradeoffer-msg', { steamid: offer.steamid_other, type: 6 });
   return;
}
```

в `offers.getOffer`, но тогда `return` будет работать на безымянную функцию в `offers.getOffer`, а не "снаружи" как мне и нужно.
Вопрос: как заставить приложение ждать ответа в данном случае?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Асихронный return вы не сделаете, так не бывает. Приведите больше кода, т.к. проблема не в этом кусочке. Вам нужно вместо return использовать callback функцию в каком-либо варианте

```
var isAccepted;
offers.getOffer({tradeOfferId: offer.tradeofferid}, function (err, o) { 
   if (err || (o == null) || (typeof o.response.offer.trade_offer_state == "undefined")) {
      helper.msg('Cant load offer state. It can be accepted, but we cant check it. Returning');
      isAccepted = false;
      return;
   }
   if (o.response.offer.trade_offer_state == "3") {
   isAccepted = true;
   }
   else {
   isAccepted = false;
   }
   if (!isAccepted) {
      io.emit('tradeoffer-msg', { steamid: offer.steamid_other, type: 6 });
      callback()
   }
});
```

P.S. Можно конечно сделать так, чтоб этот код выполнялся как будто синхронно, но такие штуки пишут раки для крабов.

Comment: Спасибо за просвящение. У меня появилась идея как решить проблему.

Comment: Ура! наконец то я смогу видеть кто меня минусует)

Comment: @Darth, не хочу вас расстраивать, но не сможете))

Comment: Черт( ну ладно. Меня больше расстраивает что на мои вопросы никто не отвечает, чем что меня минусят непонятно за что.

Answer (score 0):

Кроме callback можно использовать промисы. Еще сожно завернуть все в генератор и с помощью yield осуществлять control flow.